# python 2.7 will not import despite adding to path

Tags: python, python-2.7

Riddle me this..

importing package disaster..why?

```
contents of yenlib:
   /var/yenlib
       - __init__.py
       - yenlib
            - __init__.py
            - json_.py

import sys
sys.path.append('/var/yenlib')
sys.path.append('/var/yenlib/yenlib')

from yenlib import json_ as json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name json_
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from yenlib.yenlib import json_`?

Comment: maybe problem is from two directory has same name.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the second "append" statement and import from yenlib.yenlib

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/var/yenlib")

from yenlib.yenlib import json_ as json
```